# Node.JS async: check if variable is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, compare, settimeout

I am trying to compare a variable.value twice, with a delay in an async function.
I have tried setTimeout, more user-created wait and delay functions, but looks like it's just not working.

Let's say I have a filling machine supperted by debian/nodejs with a scale with serial connection and its value is *required* from another js file:
`const scale = require("./scale");`
Serial connection is live in scale.js and it is returning a float and beeing updated in every ms.
Monitoring `scale.value` is working fine, it changes accordingly its real values.
However, when I try to check its value and compare with itself again after 3 sec, it looks like remained unchanged. This comparison is in an async function, which is called in every 100 ms by `setInterval`.

```
const scale = require("./scale");
value1 = -1, value2 = -2;
filling= true, failsafe = false;
//other things
setInterval(catchbutton, 100);

async function catchbutton(){

//SCALE FAILSAFE
if (filling) {
  value1 = scale.value;
   setTimeout(function () {
     value2 = scale.value;
     if (value1 == value2) {
      failsafe = true;
      }
    }, 3000);
 }
}
```

Basically after 3 sec I got a failsafe every time, no matter what is the `scale.value`.
Any idea?
(sorry for any mistake, just started JS in a few weeks).

Comment: Is this mean `scale.value` is changed every 1ms?

Comment: How about console.log(value1, value2)

Comment: And I want to know initialize code of value1, value2, failsafe

Comment: Could you add a complete script with the `setInteval` too? I think there is a race condition in the code

Comment: edited code as requested.